# Can I subclass QEvent?

Tags: qt, qt5, qevent

I tried to make a class which is a subclass of `QEvent`, but I got error after building.

My steps,
1. Create a project using Qt console template
2. create the following code

```
#ifndef MYEVENT_H
#define MYEVENT_H

#include <QEvent>
#include <QObject>

class MyEvent : public QEvent
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyEvent();

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif
```

---

```
//CPP File
MyEvent::MyEvent() :
    QEvent(QEvent::User)
{
}
```

---

```
moc_MyEvent.cpp:70:21: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'd_ptr'
    return QObject::d_ptr->metaObject ? QObject::d_ptr->dynamicMetaObject() : &staticMetaObject;
           ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
moc_MyEvent.cpp:70:21: error: 'd_ptr' is a protected member of 'QObject'
../../../../../../Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:411:33: note: declared protected here
    QScopedPointer<QObjectData> d_ptr;
                            ^
```

---

Qt5
Mac OSX 10.8.4

---

How do I solve it and why? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dcow gives corrent answer.

Your mistake is that `QEvent` does not inherit from `QObject`, and you try to do it. You should not use `Q_OBJECT` macros or you should interhit your class from `QObject` too. But it's dark side.

Comment: I was 14 seconds faster :)

Comment: Yes :). Belorussian internet is so slow.

Comment: ok, I got it. I thought all the classes from Qt is from QObject, so it become habit.

Comment: @iAsk not all! There are a lot of classes that does not! See containers, strings, QModelIndex and a lot of other.

Answer (score 2):

First of all WHY? You should write why you need this, I'm sure that your problem solution which you are trying to fix is just wrong!

Secondly problem is `Q_OBJECT` macro. `QEvent` is *not* a `QObject` so this macro is not applicable and this is why you have this error.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out: No `Q_OBJECT`. But let me add something and point your attention to a rarely used and widely unknown macro: `Q_GADGET`

*Almost* a `Q_OBJECT` for non-`QObjects`.

From the Qt Docs:

> Use Q_GADGET instead of Q_OBJECT to enable the meta object system's
>   support for enums in a class that is not a QObject subclass. Q_GADGET
>   makes a class member, staticMetaObject, available. staticMetaObject is
>   of type QMetaObject and provides access to the enums declared with
>   Q_ENUMS. Q_GADGET is provided only for C++.

Comes handy from time to time.